# Is it possible to use a template inside a template with go template

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm

Using https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/, I sometimes need to use variables in the accessed path (for kubernetes deployments).

I end up writing something like :

```
{{ if (eq .Values.cluster "aws" }}{{ .Values.redis.aws.masterHost | quote }}{{else}}{{ .Values.redis.gcp.masterHost | quote }}{{end}}
```

What I'd really like to write is pretty much `{{ .Values.redis.{{.Values.cluster}}.masterHost | quote }}` , which doesn't compile.

Is there a way to write something similar ? (so having a kind of variable in the accessed path).

Comment: Is `.Values.redis` a map or a struct? Or something else?

Comment: I believe it's a struct

Comment: I'm asking because if it's a map, you may use `{{index}}`. If it's a struct, you may add methods to it.

Comment: It's a map and `index` is the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [_helpers.tpl](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/charts_tips_and_tricks.md) file to define logic and operate with values.

**_helpers.tpl**

```
{{/*
Get redis host based on cluster.
*/}}
{{- define "chart.getRedis" -}}
{{- if eq .Values.cluster "aws" -}}
{{- .Values.redis.aws.masterHost | quote -}}
{{- else -}}
{{- .Values.redis.gcp.masterHost | quote -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

**values.yaml**

```
cluster: local
redis:
  aws:
    masterHost: "my-aws-host"
  gcp:
    masterHost: "my-gcp-host"
```

And use it in your Deployment (here's a ConfigMap example to keep it shorter)

**configmap.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: Configmap
data:
  redis: {{ template "chart.getRedis" . }}
```

**Output:**

`helm install --dry-run --debug mychart`

```
[debug] Created tunnel using local port: '64712'

...

COMPUTED VALUES:
cluster: local
redis:
  aws:
    masterHost: my-aws-host
  gcp:
    masterHost: my-gcp-host

HOOKS:
MANIFEST:

---
# Source: mychart/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: Configmap
data:
  redis: "my-gcp-host"
```

**Set cluster value to aws:**

`helm install --dry-run --debug mychart --set-string=cluster=aws`

```
[debug] Created tunnel using local port: '64712'

...

COMPUTED VALUES:
cluster: local
redis:
  aws:
    masterHost: my-aws-host
  gcp:
    masterHost: my-gcp-host

HOOKS:
MANIFEST:

---
# Source: mychart/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: Configmap
data:
  redis: "my-aws-host"
```